Using sed to remove differences in two arrays (updated ssh keys)
My aim is to updated automate the update of ssh keys in the authorized_keys file. Due to restrictions i am unable to use ansible which would have been a lot simpler.
Steps:

read keys from the file
compare the keys
print out the key that will be deleted as it is i not in the supplied array
delete the keys

Everything works except for the fact it will delete the last matching key:

if there are two keys that match in array1 and array2_from_file, it will delete the second key
To be more specific it would delete "key2" (seen below)


array1=(
    "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3... key1"
    "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1l key2"
);

path=".ssh/authorized_keys"

mapfile -t array2_from_file < "$path" #updated here removed <(cat "$path)

escape_sed_pattern() {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed 's/[\\/&]/\\&/g'
}

for key in "${array2_from_file[@]}"; do
    if ! [[ " ${array1[@]} " =~ " $key " ]]; then
        echo "To be deleted: $key"
        escaped_key=$(escape_sed_pattern "$key")

        # Remove the key from the authorized_keys file
        sed -i "/$escaped_key/d" "$path"
    fi
done

Update with more details:

Part of my goal is print the key that will be deleted to the console so it can be logged by the runner to basically be referenced as a log of what was deleted.
Arrays may be of different length (ie: a key may be added or removed later on in the script and when the automation task runs it should updated the authorized keys file)


where is the data for array1 coming from? do you read it from a file? do you enter it in your script manually? something else?

Why are you doing mapfile -t array2_from_file < <(cat "$path") instead of just mapfile -t array2_from_file < "$path"

Is the goal to prompt the user before deleting a key? Because if you just want to remove the keys of array2 that are not in array1 then you can just do a printf '%s\n' "${array1[@]}" > "$path"

@markp-fuso this is done manually (for now)

@EdMorton honestly based on my understanding i though had to use cat but will adjust.

@Fravadona the goal is to print those to the console so that it can be store in the runner as a log/record

@Drey' you could take Fravadona's code and a) use tee to send the printf output to both "${path}" as well as the console or b) run the printf a second time to send output to console

Assuming the contents of array1[] are exact line matches there's no need for the mapfile, function, and for loop.
I would expect the following to suffice:
array1=(
    "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3... key1"
    "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1l key2"
);

path=".ssh/authorized_keys"

grep -vFf <(printf '%s\n' "${array1[@]}") "${path}" > tmpfile

Now overwrite the original authorized_keys:
cat tmpfile > "${path}"      # should maintain permissions on 'authorized_keys'

rm tmpfile

#######
# alternatively:

mv tmpfile "${path}"

chmod 600 "${path}"          # (re)set permissions on 'authorized_keys'


Thank you for the reply will have this tested - however the arrays may be of different length.  For instance the array in the script may increase of decrease and will be used to update the auth keys file

It sounds like all you want to do is something like this, untested:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

path=".ssh/authorized_keys"

awk '
    BEGIN {
        split("ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3... key1" RS\
              "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1l key2",
            tmp, RS)
        for ( i in tmp ) {
            array1[tmp[i]]
        }
    }
    $0 in array1 {
        print "To be deleted:", $0
        next
    }
    { print }
' "$path"

To change the input file change awk to awk -i inplace if you have GNU awk or add > tmp && mv tmp "$infile" or similar to the end of the script otherwise.

Thank you for your reply, will have this tested and i will be attempting an inplace update as i wanted to avoid creating a new file and updating permissions

Every tool except ed that claims to do "inplace" editing (awk, sed, perl, ruby, etc.) creates a new file behind the scenes, doing that part yourself just gives you a bit more control over the result. Sounds like you might want to do tmp=$(mktemp) && cp "$path" "$tmp" && awk '...' "$tmp" > "$path"; rm -f "$tmp" or similar to ensure you don't change permissions, etc.

Assuming the final order does not matter you could use a combination of sort and comm:
#!/bin/bash

array1=(
  "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3... key1"
  "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1l key2"
)
path=".ssh/authorized_keys"
trap 'rm -f -- "$tmp"' EXIT 
tmp=$(mktemp)
printf 'Keys to be deleted:\n'
comm -13 <(printf '%s\n' "${array1[@]}" | sort) <(sort "$path")
comm -12 <(printf '%s\n' "${array1[@]}" | sort) <(sort "$path") > "$tmp"
cat "$tmp" > "$path"

